# Make the folder of image first character using php?

Tags: php

I want to create the folder with the first character of the image name using PHP.
I have simple upload form please help me to create action page.

thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code you already have please?

Comment: you know you will have a very limited amount of possible folder names if you're doing this, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$image_name = "test.jpg";
$first_char = substr($image_name, 0, 1);

mkdir($first_char);
```

[substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) [mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)